# Automate standard jupyter/ipython notebook imports

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

For at least 99% of my jupyter/ipython notebooks i use the following imports:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np

from bson import json_util, ObjectId
import json

from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import pytz

pd.set_option('max_columns', 50)

mpl.style.use('ggplot')

%pylab inline
```

Has anyone discovered any sort of solution that would allow me to do this automatically or create some sort of macro?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yep, you can do it with customized startup scripts. Mines are in `/Users/user_name/.ipython/profile_default/startup`. The scripts should be `python` score files (`.py`) and the automatic imports should go there.

The doc is [here](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/1/config/overview.html#startup-files).

If you want to have `%pylab inline` in your startup script, the script has to be stored with `.ipy` extension, to specify it is an ipython script not a regular python script. I don't think it will work right if you have the cell magics like `%pylab inline` in a regular python script.

Comment: the doc location has been moved to [link](http://ipython.readthedocs.org/en/stable/interactive/tutorial.html?highlight=startup) as of 21 Apr 2016, but CT Zhu's excellent answer still stands.

Answer (score 8):

I like to use the %load magic. Make a file with all the imports in, leave it in the home directory and start the notebook with

```
%load my_imports.py
```

This method lets you edit the imports before running them.

Comment: I guess that this has the benefit of being the "my_imports.py" at the time when you created the notebook, so if it changes later it will not break your notebook...